# gengetopt: How to parse a string without an option (like a file name)

Tags: c++, getopt, getopt-long

I'm trying to parse command line options using code generated by gengetopt, and I'm trying to figure out how to parse an extra argument (after all the other options) that has no long or short option.

I'd like to call it like this:

program [options] [input file]

ex:
program -a -b -letterc "C:\somefile.txt"
or
program -a -b -letterc somefile.txt

where the option "letterc" has no arguments.

Does anyone know how to do this using gengetopt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These should be avaiable in the `inputs` member of the `gengetopt_args_info`. There are `input_num` of them.

Comment: Thanks, needed to run gengetopt with --unamed-opts to get this.